# Pause and Resume functionality of Service through Android

Tags: android

I am stuck somewhere in my application,Actually I need to download a video in Service class,so that downloading process should occur in Background. Actually My concern is that , if user has press home button, where application closes,the  number of bytes that are downloaded,I m  storing it in shared preferences,so how should i resume my service to start downloading from that point of view?

Comment: Home button doesn't close the application!

Comment: If you will use Service, it will not stopped after moving application to background (by pressing Home)

Comment: Service always runs in background, if you press home button it doesn't matter to the service, the activity will go to background, but service always runs in background, so your video downloading shouldn't stop at all.

Comment: Dimmerg :Okay thanks,I try to implement itand let you know,If i stuck

Answer (score 0):

When homebutton is pressed you can add code handling your problem in the onPause() function.
Read more here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Hey jedi,but when i press home button , my service get stoppped!!